# Why does dovecot on localhost repeat "Disconnected (no auth attempts in 0 secs)"?

Tags: logging, outlook, imap, thunderbird, dovecot

I'm running **dovecot** 2.3.10.1 on localhost (Mac OS X Catalina) to store local email folders, as described in [this article](https://xdeb.org/post/2014/03/07/running-dovecot-as-a-local-only-imap-server-on-os-x/). I do this so different email clients (Thunderbird & Outlook) can share a set of local mail folders. The IMAP connection is unencrypted (port 143) because all traffic is within localhost. The setup seems to work fine.

Every 30 minutes or so, however, dovecot emits this log message, and I'm wondering why:

```
imap-login: Info: Disconnected (no auth attempts in 0 secs): user=<> ...
```

More detailed log for imap user `smith`:

```
Dec 14 14:36:18 imap(smith)<53580><fOlIiG62zth/AAAB>: Info: Logged out in=25513 out=219820 deleted=0 expunged=0 trashed=0 hdr_count=0 hdr_bytes=0 body_count=0 body_bytes=0
Dec 14 14:36:18 imap-login: Info: Disconnected (no auth attempts in 0 secs): user=<>, rip=127.0.0.1, lip=127.0.0.1, secured, session=<ezeLwXG2K+F/AAAB>
Dec 14 14:36:18 imap-login: Info: Disconnected (no auth attempts in 0 secs): user=<>, rip=127.0.0.1, lip=127.0.0.1, secured, session=<9VyLwXG2LOF/AAAB>
Dec 14 14:36:18 imap-login: Info: Login: user=<smith>, method=PLAIN, rip=127.0.0.1, lip=127.0.0.1, mpid=55972, secured, session=<4aOLwXG2LeF/AAAB>
```

My dovecot.conf file contains:

```
listen = 127.0.0.1
protocols = imap
ssl = no

passdb {
  driver = static
  args = password=********
}

mail_location = maildir:/Users/%u/.mail:LAYOUT=fs
mail_uid = smith
mail_gid = admin
default_login_user = _dovenull
default_internal_user = _dovecot
default_internal_group = mail
default_process_limit = 10
default_client_limit = 50

auth_debug=yes
log_path = /usr/local/var/log/dovecot/dovecot.log

# Most of the actual configuration gets included below. The filenames are
# first sorted by their ASCII value and parsed in that order. The 00-prefixes
# in filenames are intended to make it easier to understand the ordering.
!include conf.d/*.conf

# A config file can also tried to be included without giving an error if
# it's not found:
!include_try local.conf
```

To debug this issue further, I set `auth_debug=yes` and the messages expanded as follows:

```
Dec 14 15:10:26 imap-login: Info: Login: user=<smith>, method=PLAIN, rip=127.0.0.1, lip=127.0.0.1, mpid=56622, secured, session=<+LakO3K2ruJ/AAAB>
Dec 14 15:10:39 auth: Debug: auth client connected (pid=56626)
Dec 14 15:10:39 imap-login: Info: Disconnected (no auth attempts in 0 secs): user=<>, rip=127.0.0.1, lip=127.0.0.1, secured, session=<6+JlPHK2sOJ/AAAB>
Dec 14 15:10:39 auth: Debug: auth client connected (pid=56627)
Dec 14 15:10:39 imap-login: Info: Disconnected (no auth attempts in 0 secs): user=<>, rip=127.0.0.1, lip=127.0.0.1, secured, session=<uARmPHK2seJ/AAAB>
Dec 14 15:10:39 auth: Debug: auth client connected (pid=56628)
Dec 14 15:10:39 imap-login: Info: Disconnected (no auth attempts in 0 secs): user=<>, rip=127.0.0.1, lip=127.0.0.1, secured, session=<2CVmPHK2suJ/AAAB>
Dec 14 15:10:39 auth: Debug: auth client connected (pid=56629)
Dec 14 15:10:39 imap-login: Info: Disconnected (no auth attempts in 0 secs): user=<>, rip=127.0.0.1, lip=127.0.0.1, secured, session=<Pk1mPHK2s+J/AAAB>
Dec 14 15:10:39 auth: Debug: auth client connected (pid=56630)
Dec 14 15:10:39 auth: Debug: client in: AUTH    1       PLAIN   service=imap    secured session=k35mPHK2tOJ/AAAB        lip=127.0.0.1   rip=127.0.0.1   lport=143        rport=58036     resp=<hidden>
Dec 14 15:10:39 auth: Debug: static(smith,127.0.0.1,<k35mPHK2tOJ/AAAB>): Performing passdb lookup
Dec 14 15:10:39 auth: Debug: static(smith,127.0.0.1,<k35mPHK2tOJ/AAAB>): lookup
Dec 14 15:10:39 auth: Debug: static(smith,127.0.0.1,<k35mPHK2tOJ/AAAB>): Finished passdb lookup
Dec 14 15:10:39 auth: Debug: auth(smith,127.0.0.1,<k35mPHK2tOJ/AAAB>): Auth request finished
Dec 14 15:10:39 auth: Debug: client passdb out: OK      1       user=smith
Dec 14 15:10:39 auth: Debug: auth client connected (pid=56631)
Dec 14 15:10:39 auth: Debug: master in: REQUEST 3664904193      56630   1       c9362a19cc3dccb8e4f428ccf531ff51        session_pid=56632       request_auth_token
Dec 14 15:10:39 auth: Debug: static(smith,127.0.0.1,<k35mPHK2tOJ/AAAB>): Performing userdb lookup
Dec 14 15:10:39 auth: Debug: static(smith,127.0.0.1,<k35mPHK2tOJ/AAAB>): Finished userdb lookup
Dec 14 15:10:39 auth: Debug: master userdb out: USER    3664904193      smith            auth_mech=PLAIN auth_token=aa100739dca9f92518b3a0eb6b1a7cdc13e15021
Dec 14 15:10:39 imap-login: Info: Login: user=<smith>, method=PLAIN, rip=127.0.0.1, lip=127.0.0.1, mpid=56632, secured, session=<k35mPHK2tOJ/AAAB>
Dec 14 15:10:39 auth: Debug: client in: AUTH    1       PLAIN   service=imap    secured session=XZ5mPHK2teJ/AAAB        lip=127.0.0.1   rip=127.0.0.1   lport=143       rport=58037     resp=<hidden>
Dec 14 15:10:39 auth: Debug: static(smith,127.0.0.1,<XZ5mPHK2teJ/AAAB>): Performing passdb lookup
Dec 14 15:10:39 auth: Debug: static(smith,127.0.0.1,<XZ5mPHK2teJ/AAAB>): lookup
Dec 14 15:10:39 auth: Debug: static(smith,127.0.0.1,<XZ5mPHK2teJ/AAAB>): Finished passdb lookup
Dec 14 15:10:39 auth: Debug: auth(smith,127.0.0.1,<XZ5mPHK2teJ/AAAB>): Auth request finished
Dec 14 15:10:39 auth: Debug: client passdb out: OK      1       user=smith
Dec 14 15:10:39 auth: Debug: master in: REQUEST 1698693121      56631   1       60e54304a600e2e0d98172e63276a10c        session_pid=56633       request_auth_token
Dec 14 15:10:39 auth: Debug: static(smith,127.0.0.1,<XZ5mPHK2teJ/AAAB>): Performing userdb lookup
Dec 14 15:10:39 auth: Debug: static(smith,127.0.0.1,<XZ5mPHK2teJ/AAAB>): Finished userdb lookup
Dec 14 15:10:39 auth: Debug: master userdb out: USER    1698693121      smith            auth_mech=PLAIN auth_token=2664e2a55eb19534feac6f04fea5a2e9102f6de8
Dec 14 15:10:39 imap-login: Info: Login: user=<smith>, method=PLAIN, rip=127.0.0.1, lip=127.0.0.1, mpid=56633, secured, session=<XZ5mPHK2teJ/AAAB>
```

If anyone knows why I'm receiving these "no auth attempts in 0 secs" messages, I'd appreciate any insights. Thank you very much.